# Webforms URL routing root page

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

Im struggling to deploy a WebForms web application which uses URL routing. The URL routing works locally but when I deploy on a server to a non-server root folder, it doesn't redirect me to the Monitor.aspx when browsing to the root of the application.

Example: in dev it runs as http://localhost and it correctly uses Pages/Monitor.aspx

But on the server when I use http://localhost/monitor/ it gives me a 403.14 error

This is the partial, relevant contents of my global.asax 'RegisterRoutes' method:

The first line is what I expect to handle this problem (but doesn't), the second line is how I handle other pages (this doesn't work either)

```
routes.MapPageRoute("monitor-page", "", "~/Pages/Monitor.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("backup-page", "Backups/{club}", "~/Pages/Backup.aspx");
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, it turns out the routing wasn't running at all.

I had to add the following to my web.config, after that everything works properly.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
</system.webServer>
```